# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1], getting this error while automating API using HTTPClient

Tags: java, json, jackson, httpclient

I am using HTTPCLIENT to automate my project webservices and in same trying to login after getting csrf token, but I am getting this error from response and I am not able to fix this even after so many hit and trial.

```
    restClient = new RestClient();
    HashMap<String, String> headerMaps = new HashMap<String, String>(); // Add header values
    headerMaps.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headerMaps.put("Connection", "keep-alive");
    headerMaps.put("csrfToken", "test12");

 // Jackson API : to convert java class object into JSON
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Users users = new Users("test@test.com", "abcd");

 // Object to Jsonfile :mapper.writeValue(new 
    File("C:/NewEclipse/Projectn/src/main/java/com/qa/data/users.json"),users);

//  Object to json in String:String usersJsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
            .writeValueAsString(users);

    System.out.println("Users json value is----> " + usersJsonString);

    // Call the Post method
    closeableHttpResponse = restClient.postLogin(url, usersJsonString,headerMaps);

    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

    System.out.println("Value of RESPONSE STRING----> " + responseString);

    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString); //Here I am getting error mentioned in subject
```

JSON Value That I am getting is also correct :
{
"email" : "test@test.com",
"password" : "abcd"
}

Answer (score 0):

hooray I found solution to this issue by my own and now its working fine

We need to pass a cookie in header like below:

```
headerMaps.put("cookie","_csrf=value; connect.sid=value; csrfToken=value")
```